# Adding 1 Year to a Date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following date:

```
2014-10-29
```

I am trying to add one year to the date (not 365 days, but 1 year):

```js
var newDate = new Date('2014-10-29');

newDate.setDate(newDate.getFullYear() + 1);

var yyyy = newDate.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (newDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var dd = newDate.getDate().toString();

var mmChars = mm.split('');
var ddChars = dd.split('');
var newClosingDate = yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);
```

This returns `2020-04-06`, which is obviously wrong.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("2014-10-29"); 
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
```