# Javascript : Increase a Date object by a year

Tags: javascript, date, format, increment

I'm assign a new date object to my object attribute like that :

**giftObject.purshasedDate = new Date()**

which give a date format :

> Date Thu Feb 20 2020 13:36:37 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe
>   centrale)

I want to increase this date by one year, I tried :

**new Date().setFullYear(giftObject.purshasedDate.getFullYear() + 1)** but it give a number serial like this : 1613824899244

I do not understand what that number serial mean! it's a date or should a try some thing else ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding 1 Year to a Date with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923973/adding-1-year-to-a-date-with-javascript)

Comment: it's not serial number, it is the time in miliseconds since 1970. You can use it to create a new Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all dates object are timestamps.

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a
> platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that
> represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.
> Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

I think the default `new Date()` object can display itself to string by in fact it's also a timestamp.
If you want to display a date as string, you have to use the `toLocaleString()` method on Date.

I tried by updating the original date and it return the string of the date, don't know why but it's work by updating the original date.

Example :

```
let giftObject = {};
giftObject.purshasedDate = new Date();
giftObject.purshasedDate.setFullYear(giftObject.purshasedDate.getFullYear() + 1);
console.log(giftObject.purshasedDate)
```

Result : `"20/02/2021 à 13:55:49"` for my French browser

Answer (score 0):

```
const oldDate = new Date("Date Thu Feb 20 2020 13:36:37 GMT+0100")
const newDate = oldDate.setFullYear(oldDate.getFullYear() + 1)
const dateWithPlusOneYear = new Date(newDate)
console.log(new Date(dateWithPlusOneYear))
//Sat Feb 20 2021 13:36:37 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one:

```
    purshasedDate = new Date();
    purshasedDate = new Date(purshasedDate.setFullYear(purshasedDate.getFullYear() + 1));
```